# Render textured mesh of multiple materials without light

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have a textured mesh of a house consisting of 94 materials. What I would like to do is render from the inside different sections of the mesh but without the effect of light. I want the rendered equirectangular image to show the actual colors of the texture without shadows or other casts of light which might potentially change the original color of the textures. What I am getting now is just a black rendering as there is no source of light inside the mesh.

Is this possible? I've seen different posts about doing this but only focusing on one material. How should I go about tackling a arbitrary amount of materials?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways of getting control over your shadow.  Shadows, ambient occlusion, and contrast can be controlled by nodes in the compositing window to to get the look you want.

I think that turning off the shadows cast by lights falling on the objects in your room, and turning on the ambient occlusion on these materials may help.

I am not sure exactly what nodes in the compositing editor you should add in order to control the shadows in the way you want, typical choices are mix nodes, or color ramps.

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful